# How to use Page Transition in NativeScript

Tags: angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to use page transition from [routerExtensions](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/angular-navigation#specifying-page-transitions) without success. (2.3.0)

I tried in js:

```
this.routerExtensions.navigate(
    [
        'myPage'
    ], 
    {
        animated: true, 
        transition: 
        {
            name: 'flip', 
            duration: 2000, 
            curve: 'linear'
        }
    } 
);
```

and I tried in the xml:

```
<Button text="Goto myPage" [nsRouterLink]="['/myPage']" pageTransition="flip"></Button>
```

Both ways works as I navigate to "myPage" but without animations.
Is there a setting I need to change to "enable" the animations or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I know this is an old question but I was wondering if you managed to figure it out? I am facing the same issue in 2020.

Comment: Me in 2021. Does somebody have an answer?

Comment: I found that it doesn't work in children routes

Answer (score 5):

With the provided context it's difficult to say exactly why it's not working.

All you should really need to do is:

Setup the components you're routing to:

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/home' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
];
```

Inject the native router extensions in the component with your `router-outlet`

`app.component.ts`

```
import { RouterExtensions } from "@nativescript/angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {}

  public navigate(link: string): void {
    this.routerExtensions.navigate([link], {
      animated: true,
      transition: { name: 'slide' }
    });
  }
}
```

And of course have a way to call this method
`app.component.ts`

```
<StackLayout>
  <FlexboxLayout>
    <Button text="Home" (tap)="navigate('home')"></Button>
    <Button text="About" (tap)="navigate('about')"></Button>
    <Button text="Contact" (tap)="navigate('contact')"></Button>
  </FlexboxLayout>
  <StackLayout>
    <page-router-outlet actionBarVisibility="never"></page-router-outlet>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I've setup a working repo demonstrating this here https://github.com/gsavchenko/nativescript-page-transitions. These are also possible to achieve in angular not using nativescript native routing APIs.

Cheers,
let me know if there are further questions.

Comment: Property `animated: true` is the trick. Undocumented I think...

Comment: it was probably missing three years ago however, i found it in the navigation options interface here: https://docs.nativescript.org/ng-api-reference/interfaces/_router_ns_location_strategy_.navigationoptions.html

Comment: two years later the link is already stale haha...

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Groceries app by nativescript and its a great resource for all nativescript component - https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries. You can find the transition animation they have given in it.

Good Luck. If need any help ask.

Comment: I'm looking for page transition animation. not just an animation on a page load event. This is not answering my question.